# Reference to std::cout results in segfault

Tags: c++

The following code results in segfault on gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename LogT> class logger {
public:
    logger(LogT& log) : log_(log) {}
    template<typename T> LogT& operator<<(T const& t) {return log_ << "\n> " << t;}
private:
    LogT& log_;
};

template<typename LogT> class A {
public:
    void f() {
        alog << "world";
    }
    static LogT& alog;
};

logger<std::ostream> alog(std::cout);
template<> logger<std::ostream>& A<logger<std::ostream>>::alog = alog;


int main() {
    alog << "hello";
    A<logger<std::ostream>>().f();
    return 0;
}
```

Why it happens?
When the line with f() call is commented segfault goes away.

Comment: `private: LogT& log_;` I wouldn't keep references as member variables unless I know exactly what I am doing.

Answer (score 8):

```
template<> logger<std::ostream>& A<logger<std::ostream>>::alog = alog;
```

On this line `alog` refers to the exact same data member twice. Clang warns about it:

> warning: reference 'alog' is not yet bound to a value when used within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]

You want to find the global `alog` - therefore you can use the *scope resolution operator*:

```
template<> logger<std::ostream>& A<logger<std::ostream>>::alog = ::alog;
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HKoNyGdu6njot2f3)